Only retrieve records with a single ancestor node of a certain type
I have a postgres database.  In it is a table called structure.
In the structure table is an ltree field called path.  It holds data like the following
f55219.f55468.f55635.f44939.p10900.f45675.p10902
f55219.f55468.f43355.f55340.p12120
f55219.f55468.f55635.f44939.p11153.f46590.p11222
f55219.f55468.f43355.f48299.p11620

I'm trying to work out how I query the structure table to only return records with a single 'p*' value in the ltree.  In the data I've pasted above, that'd be the 2nd and 4th rows.
In case it matters, there can be any number (0 - infinity) of f* records between the two p* records in the data.
Thanks for the help!

I managed to resolve this with an inner join into the parent node, and testing to ensure none of the ancestor nodes including the parent had a p in them.  I feel there is a more elegant solution however

Something like that should work:
with structure(path) as (values
('f55219.f55468.f55635.f44939.p10900.f45675.p10902'::ltree),
('f55219.f55468.f43355.f55340.p12120'),
('f55219.f55468.f55635.f44939.p11153.f46590.p11222'),
('f55219.f55468.f43355.f48299.p11620')
)

select * from structure where path ~ '*.p*.*' and not (path ~ '*.p*.*.p*.*');
                path
------------------------------------
 f55219.f55468.f43355.f55340.p12120
 f55219.f55468.f43355.f48299.p11620
(2 rows)

First condition searches paths that has at least one label which starts with p letter. Second - searches for paths that doesn't have 2 labels which starts with 'p'.

That's so elegant.  Thanks Alexius!
